# Get data from a file between two mentioned times

Tags: unix, sed

I want to get the data from a large files whose size is approximately 25GB . I am using SED command to get the data but somehow it is not giving me correct output. Below is the format of the file :

```
PID=382 00:00:01 PID=382 Received 'bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb (10.120.174.110)
PID=382 00:00:01 PID=382 Received 'TESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTEST' from client (10.120.174.110)
PID=382 00:00:02 PID=382 Received 'TESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTEST' from client (10.120.174.110)
PID=382 00:00:02 PID=382 Received 'TESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTEST' from client (10.120.174.110)
PID=4847 00:00:03 PID=4847 Returned 'TESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTEST' fro.10.120.174.110)
PID=382 00:00:04 PID=382 Received 'TESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTEST
PID=382 00:00:04 PID=382 Received 'TESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTEST
PID=382 00:00:04 PID=382 Received 'TESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTEST
PID=382 00:00:05 PID=382 Received 'TESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTEST
PID=382 00:00:05 PID=382 Received 'TESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTEST
PID=382 00:00:06 PID=382 Received 'TESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTEST
PID=382 00:00:06 PID=382 Received 'TESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTEST
PID=382 00:00:07 PID=382 Received 'TESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTEST
PID=382 00:00:07 PID=389 Received 'TESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTEST
PID=382 00:00:07 PID=382 Received 'TESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTEST
PID=382 00:00:07 PID=385 Received 'TESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTEST
PID=382 00:00:07 PID=382 Received 'TESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTEST
PID=382 00:00:07 PID=384 Received 'TESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTEST
PID=4847 00:00:08 PID=4847 Received '<>'
PID=4848 01:00:00 PID=4848 Received '<>'
PID=4847 01:00:00 PID=4847 Received '<>'
```

Now i am trying to get the data between 00:00:02 to 01:00:00 from the sed command it is skipping few of lines

```
sed -rne '/00:00:02/,/01:00:00/ p' filename
```

Comment: What does it produce?

Comment: please explain what is your expected output and how the current command is not working...

Comment: @Sundeep it is skipping last  2 lines of the files which i have mentioned but those line to come in final output and if the time is not matching then it in output whole file data is getting printed

Comment: the `//,//` form will include only first of the ending line.. if you have consecutive ones to be included in output, you'll need some other way... there's a duplicate somewhere.. I'll try to search and let you know.. or add awk/perl solution

Comment: `whole file data is getting printed` to avoid that, again you'll need some logic to save things in buffer and then print it..

Comment: for testing purposes, I'd suggest to simplify your sample data, no need such big lines and no need for too many lines between start/end regex...

Comment: @Sundeep in simple data it is working fine for me

Comment: @Sundeep can you help me to extract the data by matching time /00:00:02/,/01:00:00/

Answer (score 0):

Consider the modified input sample

```
$ cat ip.txt
begin
begin
1234
6789
end
end
end
bar
end
0-42-1
begin
b
end
begin
a
```

The `sed` solution mentioned in OP won't match multiple ending regex and match till end of file if there is no match for ending regex

```
$ sed -n '/begin/,/end/p' ip.txt
begin
begin
1234
6789
end
begin
b
end
begin
a
```

One way to handle this is using buffers (I prefer awk/perl for this)

```
$ awk ' ef && !/end/{if(buf) print buf; buf=""; ef=bf=0}
        !bf && /begin/{bf=1; buf=$0; next}
        bf{buf=buf ORS $0}
        /end/{ef=1}
        END{if(ef && buf) print buf}
      ' ip.txt
begin
begin
1234
6789
end
end
end
begin
b
end
```

Comment: can you help me to extract the data by matching time /00:00:02/,/01:00:00/

Comment: just change begin to 00:00:02 and end to 01:00:00

Comment: If no records are matching from 01:00:00 it is printing all the data of the file

Comment: @Developer sorry, I don't think that would be the case.. if you can create small minimal example and add to question showing the failure case, it would help in testing... in any case, I've tried my best to show you a way to solve this.. you'll have to try and tweak if something's off..